# Facebook jar for android development

Tags: android, facebook

I was going through one of the tutorials where we add JTwitter.jar and work with it to post status updates to twitter. I wanted to know whether there is any similar jar file available for facebook ? If yes can anyone please provide me with the location ?

Thanks,
Adithya.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The link Pompe sent you is where you'll find the .jar but i just wanted to add that there is also a great tutorial [here](http://www.helloandroid.com/tutorials/using-facebook-sdk-android-development-part-1) that will help get you started with the facebook sdk for android.

Answer (score 1):

[facebook-java-api](http://code.google.com/p/facebook-java-api/) - a Facebook API client implemented in Java, originally derived from the official Facebook client.